# Android Alert Box Wont Stay Open

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

As the title says the alert box in my app wont stay open. The box is nested within a for loop that is checked when the button is clicked. When the loop goes to the alert box it just flashes on the screen before disappearing straight away.

Is there some sort of timer I can put on the alert box to keep it open or have I implemented the box incorrectly?

**Button w/ for loop and nested alert box**

```
Button button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.cookButton);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
            //deducting one ingredient
            final Cursor ingredients = adapter.getRecipesIngredients(recipeCode);
            final Cursor missing = adapter.missingIngredients(recipeCode);
            if(missing.getCount() == 0)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Haveeverything", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                ingredients.moveToFirst();

                String ingredient = ingredients.getString(ingredients.getColumnIndex("ingredient_name"));
                int measurement = ingredients.getInt(ingredients.getColumnIndex("measurement"));
                adapter.deductIngredient(ingredient, measurement);

            }
            else
            {

                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        context);

                // set title
                alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Uh Oh!");

                // set dialog message
                alertDialogBuilder
                        .setMessage("Opps looks like yuor out of some stuff, Want to add it to your shopping list?")
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                                final Cursor missing2 = adapter.missingIngredients(recipeCode);
                                while(missing2.moveToNext()) {
                                    String n = missing2.getString(missing2.getColumnIndex("ingredient_name"));
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Adding Missing to SHopping List: " + n, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    adapter.insertItem(n, 100, "grams");
                                }
                                SingleRecipeDisaply.this.finish();
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                                // if this button is clicked, just close
                                // the dialog box and do nothing
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });

                // create alert dialog
                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                // show it
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: You mentioned a for loop? Where is that code?

Comment: @Rohit5k2 loop might be the while loop inside positive button

Comment: Sorry my mistkae not a for loop but an if statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why have you added `finish()` in `onClick`, that must be causing the issue and your activity also must be closing, not just the `AlertDialog`.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    finish();
    ...
    ...
```

Remove `finish()` at it would work.

Comment: Good catch. This could be it.

Comment: @Mohit: It was an answer posted as kind of a question. :D

Comment: Thanks very much Harry that was it, dont know how i missed that!